# Why does Entity Framework try to create a row greater than 8060 bytes when the data type is much smaller?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create a database in Entity Framework 6 from a code first approach. I get the error:

> Index 'PK_surveyor.CONDITIONS' row length exceeds the maximum permissible length of '8060' bytes.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

The class CONDITION is defined as such:

```
[Table("surveyor.CONDITIONS")]
public partial class CONDITION : ISurveyComponent
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "char")]
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime LASTUPDATED { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int ENABLED { get; set; }

    public enum ActionTypes { JumpOnPass = 0, SetFromResponse = 1, SetResponse = 2 };

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public int ACTIONTYPE { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ActionTypes Action
            {
            get
                {
                return (ActionTypes)ACTIONTYPE;
                }
            }

    public enum TestTypes { AlwaysFail=0, AlwaysPass=1,PassIfEqual=11,PassIfNotEqual=12
            ,PassIfLessThan=13,PassIfLessThanOrEqual=14,PassIfGreaterThan=15,PassIfGreaterThanOrEqual=16
            ,PassIfEmpty=20,PassIfDisabled=30};
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public int TESTTYPE { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TestTypes Test
            {
            get
                {
                return (TestTypes)TESTTYPE;
                }
            }

    public enum LeftOperandTypes {None=-1, Response=0, Comment=1, Step=2, Club=3, Province=4, ClubPrize=5};

    public int? LEFTTYPE { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public LeftOperandTypes LeftOperandType
        {
            get
            {
            if(LEFTTYPE.HasValue)
                return (LeftOperandTypes)LEFTTYPE;
            return LeftOperandTypes.None;
            }
        }

    public enum RightOperandTypes {None=-1, Response=0, AbsoluteValue=1};

    public int? RIGHTTYPE { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public RightOperandTypes RightOperandType
        {
            get
            {
                if(RIGHTTYPE.HasValue)
                    return (RightOperandTypes)RIGHTTYPE;
                return RightOperandTypes.None;
            }
        }

    public long? PARAMID1 { get; set; }

    public long? PARAMID2 { get; set; }

    public long? PARAMID3 { get; set; }

    public long? PARAMID4 { get; set; }

    public int? PARAMINT1 { get; set; }

    public int? PARAMINT2 { get; set; }

    public int? PARAMINT3 { get; set; }
}
```

This should produce a table row about 592 bytes + header long. I can see the null handling adding a few bytes, but why is EF trying to create a row greater than 8060 bytes?

Also the exception I get asks me to "See previous errors". Any ideas on where to see these? There is no link to them in the exception.

Comment: what  are you trying to insert (httppost?) into the table?

Comment: I don't get as far as any post operations. I am truing to initialize a database in a unit test project I get to the second line in:  _ctx = new CSATContext("name=TestContext");
   var hd = _ctx.HOLIDAYS.FirstOrDefault();
It never creates the database in the first place. There is no single field size I can see here that would cause this problem. I suspect the error message is bogus and there is another problem somewhere.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I would check the "previous errors" if I knew how to find them. I just get an exception from EF with that message. No InnerException and the exception's Data dictionary does not contain anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `insert (HttpPost)` logic, that error is **NOT** related to the entire row size **BUT** single field size. The maximum data size that one column can hold is 8000 bytes. Try to see any attempt inserts that is trying to insert one or more fields that exceed this number. For example, a `Varchar` string that has over 8000 characters or `Nvarchar` string has more than 4000 characters.

Also you could check the `previous` error message, which usually shows below of the first one.

Comment: The process never gets as far as any insert or update. The database never gets created because of this error.

Comment: I get only the single exception from EF with no way to find the "previous errors". No inner exception, no Data records of any use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the Typename = "char" was throwing EF into a tizzy and causing the error. The error message was bogus.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same error message.  In my case the name of the connection string had been changed in the application configuration file, but not in the name of the DbContext constructor (parameter *nameOrConnectionString*), so EF was trying to use a non-existent connection string.